# Shell Script to check if writing has finished before SCP

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I am writing a shell script on Solaris to check if the files on the Remote Host is done writing before transferring over to Local Host. I have done a skeleton, but there are certain parts I am not sure on how to do. I did a little reading on the commands to check file size, it is stat -c %s LogFiles.txt but I am not sure as to how to check it over in the Remote Host.

```
# Get File Size on Remote Host
INITIALSIZE = 

sleep 5

# Get File Size on Remote Host Again

LATESTSIZE = 


#Loop 5 times
for i in {1..5}
do
    if [ "$INITIALSIZE" -ne "$LATESTSIZE"]
    then 
        sleep 5
        # Get File Size on Remote Host
    LATESTSIZE=
    else 
        scp -P 22 $id@$ip:$srcpath/\*.txt $destpath 
        break
done
```

Comment: How are you expecting to know when the remote file is "done writing"? What is the characteristic you are judging "done" by?

Comment: Whenever I see things like this, I recommend that you redesign the process that writes the file so that it writes to a temporary name, and then renames the file to the real name when it's done. So if the file exists, you know it's done writing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over what's happening on the Remote Host. I was told to write a script that simply retrieve the .txt file on the Remote Host.

Comment: I have a question, do I have to add "fi" after "break"?

Comment: yes, you need to. Also you might think about using an infinite loop in your case to account for longer waits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your measurement for 'done' is "file size constant for 5 sec", you can simply use `ssh` as follows:

```
ssh user@remote.machine "command to execute"
```

this can be piped or set as variable on the local machine e.g. in your case:

```
latestsize=$( ssh user@remote.machine "<sizedeterminer> <file>" )
```

Passwordless login of course would skip the askpass problem. See point 3.3 in [this manual](https://www.nsc.liu.se/systems/ssh-tutorial.pdf) or an example [here](http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2011/02/ssh-how-to-pipe-output-from-local-to.html).

Comment: "File size constant for 5 sec" is a *very* weak criteria for inferring/hoping that a file  is completely written.  The only way to **know** a file is complete is via information of some type passed from the writing process - a file `rename()` upon successful completion, passing the complete file size in some way, etc.

Comment: It indeed is not the best measure - but that is the approach in the question, and I did not alter it as this was not for what the user was asking. One could also check for the status of the original process and skip the renaming and passing of information.